# Codeigniter form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been wondering about what the difference is between a normal HTML input tag and codeigniters form helper tags()?

I can understand the need for form_open, since it allows mobility in case of you changing the webaddress, but why should you use tags like form_input, form_password, form_submit etc.

Also please explain the benefits from using $this->input->post() over $_POST[]

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advantage of using the functions of the Form helper instead of generating pure HTML is just that it's less hassle to create the form dynamically (you just pass an *array* instead of concatenating strings).
If you want to, you can write your own HTML.

And the benefits of using `$this->input->post()` is that the values have been sanitized (protected from XSS attacks), that is, but it is configurable.
Also, using `$this->input->post()` won't complain if you try to get an unset parameter.